# Jquery value to php

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to add an id value from html to php.
This is my script:

HTML CODE:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

   xy.on("click", function() {
     window.location = "/pieplots/pie.php";  
     var id=100;        //HOW CAN I ADD THIS VELUE, TO THE OPENED pie.php?
   });
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"

$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: is it a post request or a get request

Comment: do you want a ajax loading

Comment: if you want to use GET, then you can simply attach id=100 after the url, for example: `"/pieplots/pie.php?id=" + id`

Comment: why dont you include the variable in the window location and retrieve it with $_GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xy.on("click", function() {
     var id=100;        //HOW CAN I ADD THIS VELUE, TO THE OPENED pie.php?
     window.location = "/pieplots/pie.php?id=" + id;  
});
```

server side may have to be changes as below since you are sending a GET request

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Becouse you use post params, you should make a post:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url:"/pieplots/pie.php",
 data: { id: 100 }
})
```

Üdv,
Bálint

Answer (score 1):

If it is not mandatory to use `POST`, try this code in script:

```
 xy.on("click", function() {
var id=100;
 window.location = "/pieplots/pie.php?id=" + id;             
});`
```

and this one in php: 
`$id = $_GET['id']; echo $id;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the browser to make a post request (not ajax) you will have to have a `<form>` for that. Something like this could work:

```
xy.on('click', function(){
    var id = 100;
    $('<form method="post" action="/pieplots/pie.php">'+
      '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+id+'">'+
      '</form>').appendTo($('body')).submit();
});
```